# Joomla 3.5.1 - Ajax with PHP not send email

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, ajax, form

I'm having some problems with the action of an Ajax form.

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(document).on('submit', '#submitNew', function() {  
        $j.post('http://www.winetube.eu/engine.php', $j(this).serialize()).done(function(data) {
            $j("#submitNew").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $j(".result").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('fail sending request');
        });
        return false;
    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

When I hit submit on the form, everything's fine so far, but nothing gets sent to my email address.

This is the PHP for the form:

```
<?php
// Recupero il valore dei campi del form
$destinatario = 'test@test.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$country = $_POST['country']; 
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$wine = $_POST['wine'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$messaggio = "Richiesta di preventivo da: ".$name."
              E-mail: ".$email."
              Paese: ".$country."
              Quantità: ".$quantity."
              Vino: ".$wine."
              Richiesta: ".$message."";

// Valorizzo le variabili relative all'allegato
$allegato = $_FILES['allegato-visura']['tmp_name'];
$allegato_type = $_FILES['allegato-visura']['type'];
$allegato_name = $_FILES['allegato-visura']['name'];

// Creo 2 variabili che riempirò più avanti...
$headers = "From: " . $name;
$msg = "";

// Verifico se il file è stato caricato correttamente via HTTP
// In caso affermativo proseguo nel lavoro...
if (is_uploaded_file($allegato))
{
  // Apro e leggo il file allegato
  $file = fopen($allegato,'rb');
  $data = fread($file, filesize($allegato));
  fclose($file);

  // Adatto il file al formato MIME base64 usando base64_encode
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

  // Genero il "separatore"
  // Serve per dividere, appunto, le varie parti del messaggio.
  // Nel nostro caso separerà la parte testuale dall'allegato
  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

  // Aggiungo le intestazioni necessarie per l'allegato
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  // Definisco il tipo di messaggio (MIME/multi-part)
  $msg .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";

  // Metto il separatore
  $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

  // Questa è la parte "testuale" del messaggio
  $msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
  $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
  $msg .= $messaggio . "\n\n";

  // Metto il separatore
  $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

  // Aggiungo l'allegato al messaggio
  $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n";
  $msg .= " filename=\"{$allegato_name}\"\n";
  $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
  $msg .= $data . "\n\n";

  // chiudo con il separatore
  $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
}
else
{
  $msg = $messaggio;
}

// Invio la mail
if (mail($destinatario, $name, $msg, $headers))
{
  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}else{
  echo "<p>Errore!</p>";
}
?>
```

I tried everything but with no success. What could I do?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: If you're using Joomla, please make full use of the Joomla API. You shouldn't be using `mail()`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER` and should be utilising `com_ajax`. Please also check your console log for any errors.

Comment: The fact is that before working properly . Now a few days does not send the email . $ _POST I always used and I have never created problems ... Possible solutions?!

Comment: Did it stop working after the Joomla 3.6 update?

Comment: After Joomla 3.5.1 update, exactly!

Comment: And what console log errors are you getting? Without knowing what the errors are, it's hard to give any proper answer

Comment: It's not possible man because my form is custom and php of mail() function I created myself and I see no error code
. When i try to launch file engine.php message report is always "error". Why this? Thank you.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest then is using `var_dump()` for your variables down the chain

Comment: I would break down the script to just sending a simple mail to a predefined address to check first if the mailer class is working. Then try the same again but writing the post form data to the message in the mail to check if everything is ok with the delivered data. (Or just print_r with die the post and check in the dev tools the response (chrome can do that).)

Comment: This question is Unclear because we don't have enough diagnostic information.